# BF3 constantly crashes

Tags: technical-issues, battlefield-3

I bought the game a few days ago, and since then the game crashes a lot when trying to launch. It doesn't give me any message, just "stop working". 
When i'm already in a game 1 out of 10 tries it'll play normally and doesn't crash. Hope you can give me a solution, hate it when it happens.

My Hardware:

- GTX 760
- 8GB RAM
- i5 3330

Comment: Can you provide any crash logs from the game? Is it always in campaign or in a menu? Can you continually replicate the crash or is it at random?

Comment: What is the operating system? also, do you have the drivers updated?

Comment: How do other 3D games behave? Any crashes? Run some tests with Unigine Heaven DX11 and Unigine Valley Benchmarks. Let it run for at least 15 minutes.  If they crash, too, it's your GPU. I'd call either bad drivers or overheating. To rule out the latter, open the side lid of your PC case (thAT is, unless it is a laptop, otherwise, run it with some kind of under-cooler)

Answer (score -1):

From what I can tell, this isn't a hardware problem. Not only are you above minimum requirements you surpass the recommended requirements.

The **GeForce GTX 760** is one of the newer Graphics cards on the market and is well above par for Battlefield 3. **8GB RAM** is the most any gaming computer needs to run even the most demanding modern video games. The **i5 3330** is also well above par for battlefield 3 requirements.

[Battlefield 3 requirements](http://www.geforce.com/games-applications/pc-games/battlefield-3/system-requirements)

```
Minimum System Requirements

• OS: Windows Vista (SP2) 32-bit

• Processor: 2 GHz Dual Core (Core 2 Duo 2.4 GHz or Athlon X2 2.7 GHz)

• Memory: 2 GB

• Hard Drive: 20 GB

• Graphics Card (NVIDIA): DirectX 10.0 graphics card with 512 MB RAM (NVIDIA GeForce 8, 9, 
200, 300, 400 or 500 series with NVIDIA GeForce 8800 GT or higher performance)

• Graphics Card (ATI): DirectX 10.0 graphics card with 512 MB RAM (AMD ATI Radeon 3000, 4000, 5000 or 6000 series with AMD ATI Radeon 3870 or higher performance)

 Recommended System Requirements

•OS: Windows 7 64-bit

•Processor: Quad-core CPU

•Memory: 4 GB

•Hard Drive: 20 GB

•Graphics Card: DirectX 11 graphics card with 1024 MB RAM (NVIDIA GeForce GTX 560
 or AMD ATI Radeon 6950)
```

Outside of that there are only a few things I can really suggest:

1. Check your software. Unless you are running on Windows XP the only thing that may be causing you issues is your Graphics Driver. So check your Driver [**Here**](http://www.geforce.com/drivers).
2. My next piece of advice would be to unistall everything that has to do with Battlefield 3 from your computer. Then reinstall it.
3. If none of that works there are a couple threads where people are having the same [**Issue**](https://www.google.com/#fp=1&psj=1&q=battlefield+3+crashing+no+error&safe=off). I searched google for these threads, so they should be easy to find.

Comment: This really should be a comment, as that's where troubleshooting is done; you're basically taking guesses as to what the problem might be, and that's not what the answer space is for.

Comment: @fbueckert idk how you do your job sure your great at it. But when I work on computers or any sort of electronic the answer is always found by troubleshooting. Its all I've ever been taught and all I'll ever know. There is no possible way to know the exact answer.

Comment: And that's exactly why this should be a comment.  Until you manage to figure it out, and at that point, you can summarize what the problem was as an answer.